# How to calculate ROI

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out some calculation but I am unsure if I am going in the right path therefore I am seeking for your guys help in this.

I am trying to calculate a few things

1. Conversion rate for each product and overall conversion
2. ROI, Cost per acquisition, average order value for each product and overall

In order to calculate the conversion rate I have used the following formula:

Order / Sessions (I am unsure if it is the best way to find the CR)

I am facing problems to find ROI and CPA as they haven’t mention any total Investment or total cost how would I suppose to find?

To get AOV I have divided number of orders / revenue

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> **"Return On Investment"** is a financial calculation used to gauge how well the money you invest earns you even more money.
>
> **To calculate ROI you divide the earnings you made from an investment by the amount you invested.** For instance, if your company spends
>   $100,000 purchasing a product that earns you an additional $20,000
>   after a year, your ROI is 0.2 or 20 percent.
>
> You can automate your ROI calculations for products or other types of
>   investments by creating a simple, reusable Excel spreadsheet.
>
> 1. Launch Excel.
> 2. Type "*`Investment Amount`*" in cell `A1`. Widen column `A` until it is slightly larger than the text in cell `A1`.
> 3. Type "*`Money Gained from Investment`*" into cell `B1`. Widen column `B` as well.
> 4. Type "*`ROI`*" in cell `C1`.
> 5. Click your mouse in cell `A2`. Type the `$` followed by the amount of your investment. For instance if you invested $1,000 dollars, enter `$1000`.
> 6. Click your mouse in cell `B2`. Type the `$` followed by the financial gain from your investment over and above the amount you invested.
> 7. Click your mouse in cell `C2`. Type `=B2/A2` into cell `C2`. Click the ✔"check" icon to accept the formula.
> 8. Click the "%" icon on the ribbon to change the result in cell `C2` to the percentage format.
>
> **Tip:**  *"Return on assets"* is another financial calculation you can perform using Excel. ROA is a measure of your company's ability to earn money from assets like cash, equipment, land, patents or accounts receivable. ROA is calculated by dividing your business' earnings by the cash value of its assets. You can set up a quick ROA spreadsheet by entering your earnings in cell `A1` and your asset value in cell `B1`. Enter `=A1/B1` into cell `C1` and click the check mark to accept the formula.
>
> **Warning:**  If you are not careful in collecting and analyzing the numbers you use to calculate ROI, the percentage Excel calculates will provide a false picture of you business's health. For a more accurate and meaningful ROI calculation, include any money you spend for consultants, marketing, business-related trips, meals and entertainment in order to increase your sales.

**Source:** [smallbusiness.Chron.com](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-excel-calculate-roi-product-44800.html)
**More information [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=calculate%20roi%20in%20excel)**.

Comment: ...also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as [ask] and how to create a "[mcve]".